# can anyone tell me how to scale down PNG images i put in an answer

Tags: support

The answer is [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206482/exactly-what-is-the-role-of-the-zero-order-hold-in-a-hybrid-analog-digital-sampl/207926#207926), and the two PNG images in the middle are just too big.  i dunno the syntax for how to do this and i only am copying syntax from other answers.

thanks,

r b-j

Comment: Cross-site duplicate with complete information: [How to reduce image size on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253405)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you upload images using the "add images" button, the images get copied to Imgur, and multiple resolution copies are made in addition to the original. By default, the original is selected. However, you can easily change which one is used by appending a modifier to the link. For a visual example, consider the following image from your post:

[image]

The link for that picture is https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbokL.png. Now the resized copies must be different links, so they are creatively named RbokL**s**.png, RbokL**m**.png, and RbokL**l**.png. Note that I am taking the existing hashed base file name (RbokL) and adding either **s**, **m**, or **l** for the **s**mall, **m**edium, or **l**arge version.

[image][image]

[image]

Keep in mind that you need to upload them to the Imgur service for this to work (that's what the add picture button does). Your post just links to the wikimedia pictures, which is plagiarism (no attribution) and will break if they ever change the link. Please fix that.

Comment: thanks.  i didn't know about imgur uploading thing.  i just referred to images at the Wikimedia site.  i am gonna be lazy and just change the reference to the medium-sized link you created.  thanks W5VO.  (i presume you are a ham-operator.  45 years ago i was one also: WB0CCA.)