# How do I make images smaller or larger?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if there was an easy way to make images smaller or larger. How would I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can anyone tell me how to scale down PNG images i put in an answer](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5553/can-anyone-tell-me-how-to-scale-down-png-images-i-put-in-an-answer)

Comment: Cross-site duplicate with complete information: [How to reduce image size on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253405)

Comment: For the CircuitLab inserts I find that if I have a very small simple circuit I can make it display leatly in ladscape format by placing a token node or wire to the left and right of my circuit that makes the image wider than the 640 pixels and it gets scaled to a nice size.

Answer (score 11):

Found this, I thought it was pretty cool.

Source: [How to make pictures smaller?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165795/how-to-make-pictures-smaller)

> Yes, just add an **s**, **m** or **l** (lowercase) at the end of the
>   imgur link before the ".png".
>
> For example, the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tE32.png can be made:
>
> **S**mall:
>
> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tE32s.png]
>
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tE32s.png
>
> ---
>
> **M**edium:
>
> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tE32m.png]
>
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tE32m.png
>
> ---
>
> **L**arge:
>
> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tE32l.png]
>
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tE32l.png

Comment: Nice to know! Now, how to make it work with schematics drawn with CircuitLab? :)

Comment: Just found out, you can do the same to the snippet when you insert the schematic, but I got weird results with 's'. Maybe it's worth to add it to the answer, since especially simple schematics end up quite large

Comment: You should not do this with CircuitLab images, it makes them non-editable without a lot of hassle.

Comment: Also, sadly related: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5595/circuitlab-schematic-integration-we-still-get-huge-diagrams-after-3-years-any (but now we have to add a few more years)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of relying on SE or Imgur to handle images in specific ways, you can post images exactly as you want in the first place.  Keep in mind that SE displays images to a maximum of 640 pixels wide.  Therefore if you make your images 640 pixels wide or less, SE will display them exactly as you uploaded them.

Image editing software is widely available with cheap and free options, so anyone can do this.  It's useful for other things than making images for SE too.  Basic image manipulation is a capability anyone should have and feel comfortable with.  Once you learn a particular toolset, you'll probably find it easier to make images the way you want rather than learning specifics of yet another system like SE/Imgur.

This is what I do with pretty much every image I upload, including schematics.  I use Eagle to draw schematics, then export them to a image file with a Eagle script.  I have another script that runs on Windows that takes the Eagle image and filters and resizes it to a nice resolution for displaying here.  You can get a lot of information in a schematic that is 640 pixels if you lay it out with that in mind.

Photographs require a whole other set of manipulations before they are acceptable to inflict on everyone else here.  In general, you should:

**FOCUS!**  Blurry pictures need not apply.  If you can't post a good picture, don't post.  Wait until you have access to a camera that can do what you need.  There is no excuse.  When I see a blurry picture, I usually don't even bother reading the text.  I vote to close a *unclear*, downvote for dumping crap on us, and move on.

**CROP** the picture to only the useful part.  Way too often we see a little thingy in the middle of a big picture.  Don't be so lazy.  As with focus, there is no excuse.

Remember to **focus**.

Remember to **crop**.

Fix the black and white levels.  Just about any image software can automatically expand the dynamic range so that the darkest part is 0.0 and the lightest 1.0.  Don't inflict muddy grayed-out pictures on us.

Fix the color balance.  Just about any image software lets you select a point in the picture and declare it a shade of gray.  If there is nothing known white or gray in the picture, then take another one with something white slipped in.  Use that as the gray reference to the other picture.  Again, don't be lazy.  You are asking lots of other people to spend a lot more of their free time to help you than it takes you to adjust the color balance of a picture.

Fix the brightness.  Just about any image software can slosh intensity towards the bright or dark end without changing the ends of the range.  Digital camera pictures often need some "brightening" so that detail is not lost in the dark areas.

Pictures you include are part of your post, so they are part of what you will be judged by.  Just like it's rude to dump crappy writing on us without even a single proofreading pass, it's just as rude to dump crappy pictures on us without even a attempt to make them easy to look at.  In fact, since a picture is probably the first thing anyone sees, even if not at the top of the post, getting the pictures right is *more* important than the words.  There is also no foreign language excuse with pictures.

As has been said many times here before, if you wouldn't hand it in as homework, it doesn't belong here either.  In fact, we deserve better.  Your teachers are being paid to look at your homework, but the people you are asking to look at your question are volunteers doing it in their free time.

Comment: " Just like it's rude to dump crappy writing on us without even a single proofreading pass". "if you wouldn't hand it in as homework, it doesn't belong here either". It appears all this does not apply to sloppy writing. Like using "thru" instead of "through".

Comment: @SredniVashtar https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thru

Comment: The problem with "if you wouldn't hand it in as homework, it doesn't belong here either" is that my experience tells me that people have far lower standards than I would have expected regarding what passes as acceptable for homework.

Comment: @pipe, yes that's basically the definition of sloppy writing. "some technical journals" publish also 'original research' on overunity machines, or other bullshit, so? Try to hand in a master thesis with 'thru'.

Comment: @SredniVashtar Well, although we require a decent level of English here, we should not be elitists. Definitely we don't specifically require PhD or Research article fussiness about English. BTW, if we were to be that fussy, what about American vs. British? Would you accept centre instead of center of vice versa? Some Journals make (or at least made) a difference about it. And this is an easy choice even for a non-native speaker with a bit of upper education in English. What about synchronize vs. synchronise? Which is AmE and which is BrE? ...

Comment: @SredniVashtar ... We are not definitely here to enforce an English standard. There is a difference between dumping on us sloppy English full of "U 2 can do this" or "I dunno Y" slang (or, worse, leetspeech) and writing basic, understandable, English even with some grammar mistake.

Comment: Nice points, Olin. This is what I try to do every time I post a photo. Although I suspect you are a bit more fussy (given your photography background end expertise) about points 5, 6 and 7. ;-) Anyway, as you say, it is not difficult at all to focus most subjects on a test bench even with crappy phones (especially sheets of paper with notes on them). And cropping (and scaling/adjusting resolution or size) is almost as easy using freely available tools.

Comment: I would recommend a nice little program that I've been using for years: [FastStone Image Viewer](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDownload.htm) (fow Windows users; free for non-commercial **or educational use**!). Very robust; it does the basic things in a breeze with uncluttered interface; very lightweight and it comes in a portable version, too (so you can always take it with you on a pendrive)!

Comment: @LorenzoDonati the problem is when the author of those mistakes reverts back the corrections, essentially stating that there are A-series posters (who are above the rules) and B-series posters, who should follow the rules.

Comment: @SredniVashtar Again, it depends on which kind of corrections are made. If someone corrected typos or grammar mistakes in my posts, that would be ok. If someone changed the style of my English, that wouldn't be ok, even if the corrections aimed at an higher style of English. Remember the **first rule of editing on SE network: *respect the intent of the original poster***. If I chose that set of words to convey the content, that must be respected if the English is grammatically correct. No one has the right to put words in anyone's mouth. It happened before to me, and I rolled back the editing.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati, I see: for A-series posters the rules must be interpreted, while for B-series posters, they must be applied. Changing 'thru' into 'through' changes the intent of the poster, right. LOL.

Comment: @SredniVashtar I see that you like to put words in the mouth of others. There are no series A and B posters. The fact that at a certain level "thru" (since you insist on that) is not considered acceptable doesn't mean that it is wrong. I hope [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thru) is enough high level source for your tastes. It is marked "US not standard", it doesn't mean it is wrong.....

Comment: @SredniVashtar ...  Do you want to enforce your variant of English and start edit wars? Then it is you that are not following the rules. There is no rule that says that SE posts must follow a well defined English standard.

Comment: @SredniVashtar To be more precise: the first absolute rule of SE is "be nice". Would you consider nice a person that continually corrects you while you are speaking because he thinks that your variant of English is wrong?

Comment: @LorenzoDonati correcting "thru" with "through" means to make the writing more formal (as should be the aim of this site: producing answers of a certain quality) , not 'changing the intent of the writer', nor 'putting words in the mouth of others'. The one starting an edit war is the original poster reverting back the corrections, not the other way around. You are simply confirming what I wrote before about rules. They are not the same for everyone.

Comment: @SredniVashtar "means to make the writing more formal (as should be the aim of this site: producing answers of a certain quality)". Sorry, no. You are mistaking formality with quality. The aim of this site is quality, not form. You can have the former without having a high degree of the latter. Example: The famous "Art of Electronics" book by Horowitz and Hill. I hope no one disagree about it being high quality, but it is famous for its lack of formality. The authors even make a point that its their informal style that helps understanding.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati H&H use "through" not "thru". You might ask yourself why. According to your metric, use of eye-slang should be allowed, too, since that's only 'form'. Also, let's forget about resizing pictures & formatting text, that's 'form' 2. All this 2 defend "thru", LOL. You are just confirming my point on class A and class B users. Now, if you'll excuse me, I'll use my time for something with a greater probability of success, like getting police jailed for shooting unarmed black people.

Comment: @SredniVashtar You still answer with using ad hoc arguments (you mentioned "thru" as an example, and I cited a reputable source indicating it is not wrong; again you reply H&H use "through", but that's not the point, since you seem to know that text, you must know that their style is so informal it won't pass always a "scientific paper style" test). Moreover you add sarcasm and "LOLs", instead of pointing out supposedly broken SE rules, as I did. Since now I see that your attitude doesn't appear to be constructive, and your replies don't try to address my counterarguments, I give up too.